# pythontex - reading data from a file

Tags: python

This is about a file location problem while using `pythontex` (which works great!)

I have some python code within `\begin{pylabblock} \end{pylabblock}` where I am reading in data from a file in the current directory

### code fragment

```
filename = str(os.getcwd()+'/testdata1.dat')

x = xyread(filename)[0]
y = xyread(filename)[1]
```

the `xyread` fails - it cannot find the file in the `getcwd()`

BUT if I place a copy of the `testdata1.dat` in
a subdirectory that `pythontex` creates during compile, it works

(my tex file is named `test3.tex` and `pythontex` creates 
`pythontex-files-test3/` and if `testdata1.dat` is in that
directory, it works)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the directory that `pythontex` creates is the working directory.  This keeps everything created by `pythontex` isolated.  If you want to use the document directory as the working directory, you can use `\setpythontexworkingdir{.}` in your preamble, or `os.chdir('..')` in your Python code.

### Update

Starting with version 0.14, `pythontex`'s default working directory is the document directory. This simplifies directory handling.  This can still be changed from the TeX side with `\setpythontexworkingdir` or the Python side with `os.chdir()`.

Comment: Ah - thanks for the answer ... And oh, very helpful package indeed ... appreciate it,

Comment: Another option is just to use `../filename` everywhere, both for reading as well as writing. This will work on Unix-like systems, at least.